# Java data serialization format alternative to JSON

Tags: java, server, data-transfer

I need recommendations for data serialization format alternative to JSON

It need to be used in Java micro services environment for server to server communications

I found an [article](https://aaronparecki.com/2015/01/22/8/why-not-json) suggesting [msgpack](https://aaronparecki.com/2015/01/22/8/why-not-json)

> MessagePack is an efficient binary serialization format. It lets you exchange data among multiple languages like JSON. But it's faster and smaller.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about why you don't want to use JSON? Are you open to binary/packed data?

Comment: @Mawg I want to reduce connection time by also reducting read time for each request

Comment: By reducing the amount of data transferred? And you are ok if it takes a longer time to pack it at the server and unpack it at the client?

Comment: @Mawg I need to check and decide, but generally yes

Comment: Sounds like you have some major throughput. I would probably recommended binary packed data, BUT, you will be holding each connection open longer to allow for packing the data at the server (probably not important at the client).

Comment: Afraid this doesn't really fit this site. SR is about recommending software, not file/data formats. That is, if you're looking for a Java library dealing with such a format, please [edit] your question to explicitly say so. Otherwise we'd need to close this.

Comment: @lzzy it's stated as java . I'm not sure what should be edit

Comment: Do all servers use Java?